# How to enlarge the PlusOneButton of Google correctly?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-one

### Background

I need to put a nice G+ +1 button , but I'm required to make it about the same size as of the FB's "like" button.

### The problem

The G+ button is quite small in all of its available sizes (which are : small,medium,standard,tall) :

- https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusOneButton
- https://unionassets.com/android-native-plugin/google-button-171

Sadly, it seems the G+ +1 button is more intended to be used for the web, so most documentations and questions are about how to make it work on websites.

### What I've tried

I tried setting the width and height, and also the minimal value for them. Both didn't help.

I've also tried to use scaleX and scaleY , but it seems a bit bad in terms of scaling (which makes sense), and it also has truncated the bottom of the button for some reason:

[image]

### The question

Is it possible to make the PlusOneButton larger nicely?

How come scaling made the button truncate at the bottom?

Comment: try this https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines may be it helps you.

Comment: @Chandra This is also for the web, and doesn't say anything about how to  change the size of the button on Android.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I got it. I've scaled the parent view of the button/s that I wanted to enlarge.

In order to avoid having it shown blurry, I've set it to be just 1.2 , meaning :

```
android:scaleX="1.2"
android:scaleY="1.2"
```

Here's how it looks now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make the size of the button the same size as the FB button? So width and height are the same. Maybe you can also provide your code of those two buttons inside the layout you have.

Did you also use the [PlusOne](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusOneButton) class from Google or are you using your own button?

Comment: I used PlusOneButton , as I wrote. The size for both is wrap_content. Changing the size to be a constant one won't help. I've already tried it.